# How can I remove the link in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails website, and the following script is for showing an image on the page.  The image has a link which links to the image's path:

```
<%= if property.images[0] then link_to image_tag (property.images[0].image.url('550x412', :jpg)), user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], roperty_id => property) end -%>
```

I would like to delete the link to the image; I just want it to show the photo without a link.

Comment: Here is the script:  %= if property.images[0] then link_to image_tag (property.images[0].image.url('550x412', :jpg)), user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], roperty_id => property) end -%

Comment: Don't put your code in comments section, Edit your question, and place your code in the question only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%= if property.images[0] then image_tag (property.images[0].image.url('550x412', :jpg)) end %>`

Read about the `link_to` helper method.

Comment: Could you please help me have another look on this: <% property.images.each do |image| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(image.image.url('120x90', :jpg)), user_property_image_path(user, :id => image, :property_id => property) %>
        <% end %>

Comment: `<% property.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag(image.image.url('120x90', :jpg)) %> 
<% end %>`